# Refreshing content, not load

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

So I've got this code snippet

```
setInterval(function(){
$("#shows_today").load("URL");
}, 1000);
```

And I've also got a include (PHP) to first load the shows today... But when the JS over get's trigged it instead of like refreshing the current loaded page with include it adds it again so the result gets showed at once... How do I do so it more like refresh then adds?

Answer (score 4):

You are accessing a server resource every second and consider how many such request will be sent if it accessed with multiple users over a period of time.

Anyways.. for an effect like refresh.. try `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`

```
setInterval(function(){
   $("#shows_today").fadeOut(200); // fade out current content
   $("#shows_today").load("URL", function () {
       $(this).fadeIn(100);
   });  // fades In new content

}, 30000); //30 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#shows_today").empty().load("URL");
```

According to your question you want to clear anything that's there and completely refresh that area of the page. The empty function removes all child elements, and then the load call is chained after it so it's acting on the same object.

Comment: *"Try this:"* is a [subpar answer decoration](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help10). Instead please add a slim explanation of *what* your code does, *why* you'd recommend it, or *how* you came to the conclusion. (In particular because OPs post isn't easy to understand.)

Comment: `.empty()` before `.load(url)` *shouldn't* make a difference since `.load` completely replaces the content of the target element anyway.

Comment: **jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document.**